# необходимо что бы блок исчезал через несколько секунд

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю так не работает, в чем может быть проблема?

```
$('#editPasswordBox').fadeOut(400,"fast");
```

Comment: через несколько секунд после чего?

Comment: ошибки в консоли? Второй параметр уберите, начнем с этого. Он значит не то что Вы пытаетесь сделать. http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, может `fast` ссылка на функцию?

Comment: Если вам надо, чтобы блок начал исчезать через несколько секунд, то вам таймер нужен, а тут вы указываете время в течение которого элемент скрывается в мс. А скрываться он начнет сразу после выполнения сего кода. [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) вам, возможно, нужен.

Comment: @Yuri, нет, не может. "fast" - это вполне себе строка а не идентификатор.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму дак там и передается строка с именем функции

Comment: @teran нет. Первое поле - скорость, второе - тип анимации, а третье уже функция

Comment: @teran, а да, действительно передается строка с именем функции, был неправ) Но мне кажется это строка не рандомное имя а некий предопределенный список встроенных функций. Могу конечно чушь нести, с ходу не знаю. Но то что "fast" это алиас для 200 мс первого параметра - это инфа 100)

Comment: @Mikl после клика по елементу.    $('#restoreboxclose').click(function(){
     $('#restoreBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
      $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
     });
    });